# What user does apt-get install software under?

Tags: debian, permissions, apt, sudo, users

I just installed some software using `apt-get`, and its owner and group is "logger". Since I installed the software using `sudo`, why isn't the owner and group "root"?  I am pretty sure about a year ago, I renamed user `pi` with the new name `logger`.  Could this have caused it, and if so, why?

```
michael@rp3:~ $ ls -l /usr | grep local
drwxrwsr-x  12 root staff  4096 Dec 23 16:49 local
michael@rp3:~ $ ls -l /usr/local
total 32
drwxrwsr-x 2 root staff 4096 Dec 23 16:47 bin
drwxrwsr-x 2 root staff 4096 Apr 10  2017 etc
drwxrwsr-x 2 root staff 4096 Apr 10  2017 games
drwxrwsr-x 2 root staff 4096 Apr 10  2017 include
drwxrwsr-x 4 root staff 4096 Jun  4  2017 lib
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root staff    9 Apr 10  2017 man -> share/man
drwxrwsr-x 2 root staff 4096 Apr 10  2017 sbin
drwxrwsr-x 7 root staff 4096 Dec 23 15:20 share
drwxrwsr-x 2 root staff 4096 Apr 10  2017 src
michael@rp3:~ $ sudo apt-get install test-client
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  test-utils
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  test-client test-utils
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,575 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  test-utils test-client
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Selecting previously unselected package test-utils.
(Reading database ... 41030 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../test-utils_0.1.1-jessie_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking test-utils (0.1.1-jessie) ...
Selecting previously unselected package test-client.
Preparing to unpack .../test-client_0.1.2-jessie_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking test-client (0.1.2-jessie) ...
Setting up test-utils (0.1.1-jessie) ...
Setting up test-client (0.1.2-jessie) ...
michael@rp3:~ $ ls -l /usr/local
total 40
drwxrwxr-x 6 logger logger 4096 Dec 23 16:49 test-client
drwxrwxr-x 3 logger logger 4096 Dec 23 16:49 test-utils
drwxrwsr-x 2 root   staff  4096 Dec 23 16:49 bin
drwxrwsr-x 2 root   staff  4096 Apr 10  2017 etc
drwxrwsr-x 2 root   staff  4096 Apr 10  2017 games
drwxrwsr-x 2 root   staff  4096 Apr 10  2017 include
drwxrwsr-x 4 root   staff  4096 Jun  4  2017 lib
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   staff     9 Apr 10  2017 man -> share/man
drwxrwsr-x 2 root   staff  4096 Apr 10  2017 sbin
drwxrwsr-x 7 root   staff  4096 Dec 23 15:20 share
drwxrwsr-x 2 root   staff  4096 Apr 10  2017 src

michael@rp3:~ $ cat /etc/passwd | grep 'apt\|logger\|root\|michael'
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
michael:x:1001:1001:,,,:/home/michael:/bin/bash
_apt:x:109:65534::/nonexistent:/bin/false
logger:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/logger:/bin/bash
michael@rp3:~ $ cat /etc/group | grep 'apt\|logger\|root\|michael'
root:x:0:
michael:x:1001:
wireshark:x:114:michael
logger:x:1000:
michael@rp3:~ $ sudo cat /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
michael  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
anton   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
michael@rp3:~ $ ls -l /etc/sudoers.d
total 8
-r--r----- 1 root root  27 Oct 18  2016 010_pi-nopasswd
-r--r----- 1 root root 958 Jan 11  2016 README
michael@rp3:~ $ sudo cat /etc/sudoers.d/*
pi ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
#
# As of Debian version 1.7.2p1-1, the default /etc/sudoers file created on
# installation of the package now includes the directive:
#
#       #includedir /etc/sudoers.d
#
# This will cause sudo to read and parse any files in the /etc/sudoers.d
# directory that do not end in '~' or contain a '.' character.
#
# Note that there must be at least one file in the sudoers.d directory (this
# one will do), and all files in this directory should be mode 0440.
#
# Note also, that because sudoers contents can vary widely, no attempt is
# made to add this directive to existing sudoers files on upgrade.  Feel free
# to add the above directive to the end of your /etc/sudoers file to enable
# this functionality for existing installations if you wish!
#
# Finally, please note that using the visudo command is the recommended way
# to update sudoers content, since it protects against many failure modes.
# See the man page for visudo for more information.
#
michael@rp3:~ $
```

Comment: what groupid has logger on your system? maybe your group ids got mixed up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apt-get`, or rather `dpkg`, installs package contents using whatever user is recorded as owning the various files in the package. This is typically `root:root`, but can be anything; you’ll commonly see `root:games` in game packages, `root:www-data` for certain directories in web-server-related packages, etc. (Ownership and permissions can also be set by maintainer scripts, but that’s usually not necessary.)

If a package is created manually on a Raspberry Pi-style system, without paying too much attention to ownership (and not using `fakeroot`), it would perfectly be possible to end up with a package containing files owned by `pi:pi`, identified numerically. On your system, these would end up belonging to `logger:logger`.

You can see the ownership information contained in a packages by using `dpkg-deb -c`.

Comment: Thank you Stephen,  Before getting your answer, I removed the package (with and without using `purge`), deleted user `logger`, rebooted, reinstalled, and now user:group are both 1000 (old pi's and then old logger's numerically id).  Then, I used `dpkg-deb -c /var/cache/apt/archives/thepackage.deb`, and I see the file owner/group is `michaelOnServerWhoBuiltPackage`, and as you likely expect, this user's id/groupId is `1000`.  I expect/hope this is not expected behavior as it arbitrarily gives ownership of files based on chance that user's on the two machines have the same numerical user id.

Comment: Yes, you’re not supposed to produce packages whose files are owned by non-system users.

Answer (score 4):

Debian packages can set file permissions and ownership in their postinst script.

Comment: I had preinst and postinst and postrm scripts associated with the file, but they do not change the owner/group.  Interesting, they too had user/group "logger".  I then used apt-get to remove the package and then physically removed the pre/post inst/rm files, and finally reinstalled, and they again have the same user/group.  While these type of files "can" do such a thing, they are not in my case.